# URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could not be followed. - Facebook/Nginx issue

Tags: facebook, nginx

I have used Facebooks sharing debugger to highlight an issue on the website

```
URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could not be followed.
```

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.badgerbookings.com

This is also stopping it accepting the url in the privacy policy when creating an app. [image]

I have researched and made sure to add all OG meta tags. I also "reduced" down the redirects on my nginx to only support a http > https redirect which to me seems pretty standard.

It still produces the error on both the debugger and the Privacy Policy URL.

My Nginx config:

```
server_tokens off; #Enables or disables emitting nginx version on error pages and in the “Server” response header field

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://www.badgerbookings.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        server_name www.badgerbookings.com  badgerbookings.com *.badgerbookings.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; # allow websockets
                proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr; # preserve client IP
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
                proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
         }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/badgerbookings.com-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/badgerbookings.com-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to [Facebook Developer's policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) page.

Scroll down to this bit:

> Privacy Policy
>
> a. Provide a publicly available and easily accessible privacy policy
> that explains what data you are collecting and how you will use that
> data.

Now run

`curl https://badgerbookings.com/terms`

Are you looking at an easily accessible privacy policy which is publicly available at that url?

Comment: fair point. I presumed they would attempt to read React frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe having IPv6 issues which can be resolved as simple as adding a `listen [::]:443 ssl` directive in you SSL `server` block.

If that doesn't fix it, try redirecting with a matching `if` directive

```
if ($scheme != "https") {
    return 301 https://www.badgerbookings.com$request_uri
}
```

This is best if you unite both server blocks in one, to avoid more code. Just delete the non-https one and insert port 80 listen directives on the other one as well, with that conditional redirect, this way your code will be even slimmer.

Comment: Tested both and each failed to fix the issue, unfortunately. Also not too sure what [::] does?

Comment: [::] means what IPv4 0.0.0.0 means, but for IPv6